# Sending php variable through file_get_contents()?

Tags: php

Ok, so I'm trying to send id variable using `file_get_contents()`.

```
<?php $id = '123456'; echo file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/user.php"); ?>
```

But it doesn't work.

I will be using this for sending variable data to an external url, this is why I'm using `file_get_contents()`.

The below `include()` works with a local site, but not the external:

```
<?php $id = '123456'; include 'user.php'; ?>
```

In user.php:

```
<?php echo $id; ?>
```

But I need to do this with the external website...

And no, changing php.ini or allowing `include()` by changing the server settings is not what I'm looking for.

Is there any way to send variable using `file_get_contents()` ?

Any help or a hint would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Thinks about this!! If this was possible a hacker could simply send a script to any PHP based web site and Do anything they wanted to do. So no! **luckily** this is not possible

Comment: _"And no, changing php.ini or allowing include() by changing the server settings is not what I'm looking for."_ - it would not help you to begin with, because the basic issue here is that you are making an HTTP request, instead of reading the actual PHP code via the file system - making an HTTP request will only get you the _output_ of the script, not the code. The only way to achieve what you want, is to pass the value as a query string parameter. And then the remote script must of course explicitly read that parameter, you can not just insert variables into scripts on different servers.

Comment: Got it. thanks for the naswers.

Answer (score 2):

Found a work around.
Not very delicate, but did the job:

Inside 1.php:

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/
```

Inside 2.php:

```
">Link</a>
```

And then simply:

```
<?php echo file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/1.php"); ?>
?id=123456
<?php echo file_get_contents("https://www.example.com/2.php"); ?>
```

This will result a link of:
https://www.example.com/?id=123456

And you can basically change anything that's before and after the `?id=123456` on those two external php files